# Ubuntu 22 - Active Directory login issue (already joinded to domain)

Tags: 22.04

During the installation Ubuntu machine joined to domain, and machine is in correct OU.
Via GNOME I can add new user (it appears in login screen) but not accept the password. (password checked).

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Please tell us how you have joined the domain. Are you using WinBind or SSSD? _[There may be other options for AD logins, but those are the two I know—and I confess, I STILL have problems after 2 years configuring systems with SSSD]_. I'm not sure you _can_ create an AD user from the Linux side. Do `getent passwd USER` (where USER is a user you know is in the AD, but not a local Linux user), and show us the output. If you don't find that user, you don't have AD logins configured.

Comment: At that screen I ticked the "Use Active Directory" and next screen I entered domain name and Adminsitrator credentials. Machine appeared in AD after installation,

https://www.linuxtechi.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Create-User-Set-Host-Name-Ubuntu-22-04-Installation.png

At Gnome -> Settings -> Users I Add Users and chosed Enterprise Logins and used my AD credentials which accepted and user appeared at Logon Screen. (but at logon screen not accept password. While  on all other window accepted.)